# An admissible numbering of an acyclic quiver

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, reflection, quiver

Let $Q$ be an acyclic quiver. In [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC&redir_esc=y), we read that

> there exists a bijection between $Q_0$ (set of vertices of $Q$) and the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that if we have an arrow $i \to j$, then $j > i$; indeed such a bijection is constructed as follows. Let $1$ be any sink in $Q$, then consider the full subquiver $Q(1)$ of $Q$ having as set of points $Q_0 \setminus \{1\}$; let $2$ be a sink of $Q(1)$, and continue by induction. Such a numbering of the points of $Q$ is called an **admissible numbering**.

Let us do an example. Let $Q$ be the (acyclic) quiver:
\begin{equation*}
1 \gets 2 \to 3 \gets 4 \to 5
\end{equation*}
For example, $1$ is a sink, so we remove $1$ and we're left with:
\begin{equation*}
 2 \to 3 \gets 4 \to 5
\end{equation*}
Then we decide to remove $5$, and so we get:
\begin{equation*}
 2 \to 3 \gets 4 
\end{equation*}
Now, only 3 is a sink, so we remove $3$ and I guess we're left with an empty quiver(?). So, as for our admissible numbering of $Q$, we got that the first 3 numbers are $\{1,5,3\}$ but what about the remaining $2$? Should our admissible numbering be $\{1,5,3,2,4\}$ or $\{1,5,3,4,2\}$? Or it doesn't matter? Can someone help me clarify what is the procedure in situations like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the vertex $3$ you are not left with the empty quiver but with the quiver with two vertices, $2$ and $4$. Since there are no arrows in the quiver you get two possible numbering which are admissible $\{1,5,3,2,4\}$ and $\{1,5,3,4,2\}$. Notice that you also made a choice beforehand, your first vertex could be either $1$, $3$, or $5$. In the next step you can remove another one of those three. In the third step it even depends on what you have done before, i.e. if your first two choices were $1$ and $3$, you can take $2$ as your third choice. In this theory it often only matters that there exists an admissible ordering and in the concrete constructions you work with a particular fixed one of those. But there will in general be many possible admissible numberings and not all the constructions are independent of the ordering.

Comment: thank you for your answer! You said: "if your first two choices were $1$ and $3$, you can take $2$ as your third choice". Did you mean to say $5$, as my third choice?

Comment: @amator2357 $5$ is another option. But also $2$ is a sink if you have removed $1$ and $3$ before.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something here because I really can't see how $2$ is a sink if we have removed $1$ and $3$ before.

Comment: I'm reading: " a sink of $Q$ means a vertex $v \in Q_0$ such that no
$e \in Q_1$ starts at $v$". So, by definition, $2$ is a sink (after we remove $1$ and $3$). Thus, we could've indeed picked $2$. Is that the correct reasoning here?

Comment: @amator2357 Yes, indeed. This is the correct reasoning.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that, given an acyclic quiver $Q$, to find one if its admissible numbering quickly, we can look at the adjacency matrix of $Q$, find the rows of $0$'s-these correspond to sinks in $Q$ - position of such rows will give us the first elements of our admissible ordering and then the remaining elements of that admissible numbering correspond to the positions of non-zero rows and their order in our admissible numbering doesn't matter?

Comment: @amator2357 In your example yes, but not in general. Your algorithm fails if and only if the original quiver has paths of length greater than one. The first step of your proposed algorithm is correct: You should find the 0-rows these correspond to all the sinks, then you can remove them in any order. Then you should remove the corresponding rows and columns from your adjacency matrix (i.e. remove the vertices) and then proceed inductively by again looking for zero rows.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thank you for all your help @Julian!